# cudaFree - Invalid device pointer error

Tags: opengl, cuda

I am trying to deallocate the device memory `dev_inp` that I had allocated in my CUDA + OpenGL interoperation code. Upon error checking, I received the `Invalid Device Pointer` error, and the program stopped execution at the `cudaFree(dev_inp);` call at the end of my `renderScene()` function. Everything renders fine, but I am worried about a memory leak.

Questions:

a. Why am I not able to release the local device memory that I had allocated? I unmapped the `cuda_resource` from the pixel buffer object, and unregistered the resource as well.

From section B.17 in the CUDA C programming guide:

`Memory allocated via malloc() cannot be freed using the runtime (i.e. by calling any of the free memory functions from Sections 3.2.2).`

So, this leads me to two other questions:

b. I have not `malloc`ed memory in a kernel because I don't have one. So, utilizing the `cudaFree` function should (technically?) work here right? Is it up to the programmer to deallocate the memory provided to locally-defined pointers, or does the nvcc compiler take care of the deallocation as the program exits or if it goes out of local scope? I don't want a memory leak in my code, so I feel safer by taking care of deallocating memory that I previously allocated.

c. Is it prudent to call `cudaDeviceReset()` at the end of the `renderScene()` function, so that the primary CUDA context is destroyed (along with its variables and pointers, as per the CUDA C Programming Guide)? I have seen that NVidia Visual Profiler doc also mentions this: [cudaDeviceReset()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#flush-profile-data)
When I do call it, the rendering seems to happen slower than usual. It would be great if I could simply `cudaFree` the memory here, but I can't seem to get it to work.

**Full code:**

```
#define GET_PROC_ADDRESS( str ) wglGetProcAddress( str )

GLuint tex; 
GLuint pbo;
struct cudaGraphicsResource *cuda_resource;    

PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC    glBindBuffer     = NULL;
PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC glDeleteBuffers  = NULL;
PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC    glGenBuffers     = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC    glBufferData     = NULL;

// ==========================================================================================
// CUDA ERROR CHECKING CODE
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) getchar();
   }
}

// ==========================================================================================

void initCUDADevice() { 

    gpuErrchk(cudaGLSetGLDevice( cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId() ));    

}

// ==========================================================================================

void changeSize(int w, int h) {

    //cudaDeviceReset();
    //initCUDADevice();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
    // (you cant make a window of zero width).
    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio =  w * 1.0 / h;

    // Use the Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    // Reset Matrix
    //glLoadIdentity();

    //// Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    //// Get Back to the Modelview
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

// ==========================================================================================

void renderScene(void) {

    // Clear Color and Depth Buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();

    // ====================================================================================
    // initiate GPU by setting it correctly 
    //initCUDADevice(); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // read the image that needs to be textured 

    Mat image, flipped;
    image = imread("K:/Ultrasound experiment images/PA_175.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   // Read the file from disk

    if(!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;


    }

    cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);

    imshow("OpenCV - image", image);    // displays output

    // ====================================================================================
    // allocate the PBO, texture, and CUDA resource

    glBindBuffer    = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBindBuffer");
    glDeleteBuffers = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glDeleteBuffers");
    glGenBuffers    = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glGenBuffers");
    glBufferData    = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBufferData");

    // ====================================================================================
    // generate the pixel buffer object (PBO)

    // Generate a buffer ID called a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)
    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);

    // Make this the current UNPACK buffer (OpenGL is state-based)
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);

    // Allocate data for the buffer. 4-channel 8-bit image
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned char) * flipped.rows * flipped.cols, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);

    gpuErrchk(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_resource, pbo, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone)); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // create the texture object 

    // enable 2D texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // generate and bind the texture    
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // put flipped.data at the end for cpu rendering 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,  image.cols, image.rows,  0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    // put tex at the end for cpu rendering 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ====================================================================================
    // copy OpenCV flipped image data into the device pointer

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    unsigned char *dev_inp; 

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) );

    size_t size; 
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dev_inp, &size, cuda_resource) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(dev_inp, flipped.data, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) ); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // bind pbo and texture to render data now 

    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    //
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, flipped.cols, flipped.rows, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(cuda_resource));
    gpuErrchk( cudaThreadSynchronize());

    //gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_inp));

    // ====================================================================================
    // map the texture coords to the vertex coords 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    glEnd();

    glFlush();  // force rendering

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //glutSwapBuffers();
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_inp));        // <--- Error here
    //cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(cuda_resource);

}


// ==========================================================================================


int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    // init GLUT and create window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024,256);
    glutCreateWindow("CUDA + OpenGL interop");


    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    //glutIdleFunc(renderScene);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is not necessary and should be removed from your code:

```
gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );
```

This line creates a device allocation, and assigns the pointer for that allocation to `dev_inp`.

The problem arises here:

```
gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dev_inp, &size, cuda_resource) );
```

This line acquires a *new* pointer, derived from the `cuda_resource` object, to another, different allocation, and places that pointer into `dev_inp`, **overwriting** your previously allocated pointer (from `cudaMalloc`).  The new pointer acquired in this line already has an underlying device allocation.  You do not need to allocate for it separately/additionally at this point.

At this point, if you try to free `dev_inp`:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_inp));        // <--- Error here
```

You are attempting to free data that your program did not explicitly allocate (via `cudaMalloc`), and is furthermore a necessary component of the persistent (at this point) `cuda_resource` object.  You don't want to do that.  Unfortunately, the original pointer that was placed in `dev_inp` is now lost (overwritten), and so there is no way to "free" it in your program, and you will have a memory leak, as long as the program is executing.

The solution is not to perform the extra, unneeded allocation:

```
gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );
```

This then means that the corresponding `cudaFree` operation should be eliminated as well:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_inp));        // <--- Error here
```

I would not use `cudaDeviceReset` anywhere in a CUDA code, especially a CUDA/OpenGL code, until the program is actually exiting.  There are a few other very specialized situations where you might want to use `cudaDeviceReset` before the point at which you actually intended to exit your program, but they don't apply here.

Comment: I see, now it makes sense, thanks! However, if `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()` returns a pointer to the cuda_resource as per the docs [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__INTEROP_ge7f893864a3d38a630e71a99f5a4e17f.html), can I deallocate that memory? Would the memory be deallocated by calling `cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource()`?

Comment: You *don't want* to deallocate the memory.  The *underlying* resource is an OpenGL resource (in this case), and you don't want to deallocate it in CUDA code.  It should be managed from OpenGL.  study the definition and behavior of [cudaGraphicsMapResources](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gb7064fb72e54d89d0666e192b45d35cc)  Specifically, since the pointer (that was placed in `dev_inp` by `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer`) was *not* allocated via a call to `cudaMalloc`, you cannot free it via a call to `cudaFree`.

Comment: Oh, right! OpenGL is the "owner" of the actual memory, and CUDA just shares access to the data present at the start of that memory location. Thanks for clearing that up!